# Is there an option in sql developer to verify with the user if he really wants to close sql developer?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there like an option in SQL developer that confirms with the user if he/she really wants to close the window? I know this might sound silly but I always accidentally hit the close button probably because I'm working on dual screens, and when I click it then it'll close without any confirmation.

I can only see options upon closing on worksheets but not on the sql developer window

Comment: Doesn't look like there is, no. The only way to get close to that I can see is to have 'prompt for save file on close' checked in the worksheet preferences, and leave a worksheet open with unsaved changes. Not exactly elegant though. Might be worth asking/requesting this on [the SQL Developer forum](https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/development_tools/application_development_in_pl_sql/sql_developer_(not_for_general_sql_plsql_questions)).

Comment: thanks Alex, I'll request that there. I went to Jeff's blog site and asked him as well.

Answer (score 0):

easiest workaround would be to make the two monitors appear to be not on the same height. on my window display settings this is what I did, this way if the mouse accidentally goes to the external screen, it will be far away from the close button of sql-developer

[image]